# Hide empty custom field

Tags: functions, custom-field

I've created a custom field in Woocommerce to link to games that have the same title but are on different platforms. It basically shows **Also available on:** XBox One or PS4.
It works well but when the field is empty it shows only **Also available on:** which looks sloppy and is confusing.

How can I hide the custom field when it's empty? The code is below and the custom field is also_available. I've placed it in my functions.php

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'also_available_on_ps4', 38 ); 
function also_available_on_ps4() {
    global $product;
    if ( has_term( 'ps4-games', 'product_cat' ) ) {
    echo '<b>Also available on:</b>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'also_available', true );
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me. TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want is to hide the text when meta is empty.
You can put a conditional check for meta before print:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'also_available_on_ps4', 38 ); 
function also_available_on_ps4() {
    global $product;
    if ( has_term( 'ps4-games', 'product_cat' ) ) {
        if(get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'also_available', true )){
            echo '<b>Also available on:</b>' . get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'also_available', true );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome @Aniruddha Gawade. Works perfectly. I could kiss you.